# Arduino Uno Multiple Modules

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I have an Arduino Uno and I want to connect;

- RFID Reader (*RC522*)
- WiFi Module (*ESP8266 ESP-01*)
- SD Card Module
- RTC (*Real Time Clock - DS1307*)

Same time but pinouts are not enough. Is there a way to doing this with Uno or I have to buy an Arduino Mega ? I saw "*Expansion Sensor Shield*"s but I do not know what is the logic of using this ?

Regards

Comment: It depends. You need to provide more detail. Some of the devices use I²C which can share connections provided they have different addresses. Others use SPI which need individual select pins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see which device uses which communication protocol:

1. **WiFi Module (ESP8266 ESP-01)** uses Serial communication.
2. **RTC (Real Time Clock - DS1307)** uses I²C communication.
3. **RFID Reader (RC522)** uses SPI communication.
4. **SD Card Module** also uses SPI communication.

Now, the Arduino UNO supports **One I²C**, **One SPI** and **One Serial** (by default) communication port.

So, you can easily connect your **Wifi** and **RTC** modules.

Now, actual problem is: "[How to access multiple SPI interfaces on Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8425/how-to-access-multiple-spi-interfaces-on-arduino)" (and that is a solved problem).

Hope it helps and you don't have to buy an **Arduino MEGA**.